# How come Task implements IAsyncResult, but does not contain the AsyncWaitHandle member?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, task, iasyncresult

Maybe it is a silly question.

The `Task` class is declared this way:

```
public class Task : IThreadPoolWorkItem, IAsyncResult, IDisposable
```

The `IAsyncResult` interface is declared like this:

```
public interface IAsyncResult
{
    object AsyncState { get; }
    WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle { get; }
    bool CompletedSynchronously { get; }
    bool IsCompleted { get; }
}
```

But the member `AsyncWaitHandle` does not exist in the `Task` class or instances.

This code:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => { }); 
t.AsyncWaitHandle.ToString();
```

Raises this compilation error:

> Error 1   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition
>   for 'AsyncWaitHandle' and no extension method 'AsyncWaitHandle'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

However, this not only compiles:

```
System.IAsyncResult t = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => { }); 
t.AsyncWaitHandle.ToString();
```

But also works, since the member exists. What is this sorcery?

It is a compiler trick or is it being hidden in another way?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Task` implements `IAsyncResult` explicitly, so you have to cast first:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => { }); 
((IAsyncResult)t).AsyncWaitHandle.ToString()
```

Explicit implementations are defined like:

```
public class Task : IAsyncResult
{
    WaitHandle IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get { ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: So that is why I do not see it in Visual Studio through its metadata, because explicit implementations are not public. I didn't think on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The msdn docs sum it up quite nicely.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx

> The class member IControl.Paint is only available through the IControl
>   interface, and ISurface.Paint is only available through ISurface. Both
>   method implementations are separate, and neither is available directly
>   on the class.

```
interface IControl
{
    void Paint();
}
interface ISurface
{
    void Paint();
}
class SampleClass : IControl, ISurface
{
    void IControl.Paint()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("IControl.Paint");
    }
    void ISurface.Paint()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("ISurface.Paint");
    }
}
```

The takeaway here is that explicit interface implementations are private and bound with compiler magic.

Comment: It looks like a terrible thing to do. Isn't this a bend on the LSP?

Comment: @vtortola depending on your consideration of interfaces, its a straight up violation. However, interfaces are not abstract types. They are simply contracts that state you may safety cast to the interface 'type'. I'm not a fan either but it is consistent.

Comment: @vtortola I'm more concerned that you would even do this - it is a concrete SRP violation.